# Tiff equivalent of UIImage.AsPNG()

Tags: xamarin.ios, uiimage, tiff

Is there a way to get `NSData` in TIFF representation from `UIImage` instance, just the way you can get PNG and JPEG representations using `UIImage.AsPNG()` and `UIImage.AsJPEG()` methods respectively?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iOS doesn't have a native TIFF library.  You could try

- using a third party service
- find an open source C# library and port it
- find a obj-c library and bind it

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8714753/how-to-create-a-tiff-on-the-ipad) for info about a Obj-C port of ImageMagick.