# How to make libtiff for an Xcode project and an iOS application?

Tags: ios, xcode, libtiff

I have been searching up and down stackoverflow and Google for the correct way to compile and add the `libtiff` library to my existing iOS project in Xcode.

What I have done so far:

**EDIT:**

I have downloaded libtiff to my Mac after deciding to follow this advice on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8714753/how-to-create-a-tiff-on-the-ipad). I used version [3.9.6](http://download.osgeo.org/libtiff/tiff-3.9.6.tar.gz) and built it like in this [tutorial](http://tinsuke.wordpress.com/2011/02/17/how-to-cross-compiling-libraries-for-ios-armv6armv7i386/) and its [sequel](http://tinsuke.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/how-to-compile-and-use-tesseract-3-01-on-ios-sdk-5/) about SDK5. There, in the comments, I found a [script](http://pastebin.com/gE59pVgk#) I could [adapt](http://pastebin.com/q0RYrwna). I have added the resulting "dependencies" folder to my Xcode project, almost like [rakmoh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1024096/rakmoh) suggested.

However, I got linker errors as soon as I `#include tiffio.h`:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:  "_inflateEnd", referenced from:
  _PixarLogCleanup in libtiff.a(tif_pixarlog.o)
  _ZIPSetupEncode in libtiff.a(tif_zip.o)
.
... some more...
.
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7 
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I also tried the newest version of `libtiff`, but that did not change a thing, so I went back to 3.9.6, as it is compatible with the other softwares in the project. Then I asked a colleague who found out it was the `libz` library missing. From the log files he saw it must have been there during the compilation of `libtiff` and it was still missing for the linker in my Xcode project. And lo! When I added it to the frameworks (with the little + sign and browse the list for `libz.dylib`), my empty test project compiled.

Before writing an answer, I would like to do some more testing, but I have already updated the successful shell script to [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/q0RYrwna).

Thank you for your help!

Comment: For an updated answer see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30552074/compile-libtiff-for-ios-project-to-include-64bit-architecture/30552262#30552262

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have pasted a [bash script](http://pastebin.com/q0RYrwna) that cross-compiles `libtiff` version [3.9.6](http://download.osgeo.org/libtiff/tiff-3.9.6.tar.gz) on a Mac for iOS 6.1 to be used on devices and in the simulator. You will have to adapt it to your needs. Also see this [tutorial](http://tinsuke.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/how-to-compile-and-use-tesseract-3-01-on-ios-sdk-5/) for hints. It creates a fat library for both compilation targets.

[rakmoh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1024096/rakmoh)s answer is also correct, but only part of the solution. You add the folder with the fat library in the "Add Other.." dialogue he proposes.

Then you also add libz.dylib! After that, I could use `libtiff` in my app on my device and on the simulator.

Comment: It looks like this only works with Xcode 4. Can it be updated to work with Xcode 5? (gcc compiler is no longer available)

Comment: Thank you for the information. My work on that has been cancelled, because processing large image data this way was too slow. We are not trying to do it with an iPhone anymore. Now I know another reason why that has been a good idea :(

Comment: I recently discovered the GPUImage library that has lots of filters and is lightning fast on the iPhone. https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage

Comment: See [Juan Catalan](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2649732/juan-catalan)s comment below the question for an updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps for adding a library to your iOS project in XCode 4.6.2 (should be similar in old versions of XCode):

- Click on your project name in the project navigator (left pane)
- Click on your Target and select "Build Phases"
- Under "Link Binary With Libraries" click "+" (at the end of the existing list)
- Select "Add Other.." button in the popover window, it will open the file browser window
- Browse to and select the library that you want to add and click "Open"

Comment: Thank you very much. By now I am sure the library is not compiled to fit to iOS, too. And I definitely did not pose that question well enough. I will edit it to clarify my problem.