# How to save a TIFF photo from AVFoundations captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection to a file with EXIF metadata on an iPhone (iOS)?

Tags: avfoundation, tiff, exif, nsdocumentdirectory

With this question I only ask for the possibilities I have with Xcode and iOS without external libraries. I am already exploring the possibility of using `libtiff` in another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17169300/how-to-make-libtiff-for-an-xcode-project-and-an-ios-application).

**Problem**

I have been sieving stack overflow for weeks and found working solutions for every one of my problems on its own. I have 4 things that need to work:

1. I need the RGBA data as it comes from the camera, no compression whatsoever
2. I need as much metadata as possible, especially EXIF
3. I need to save in TIFF format for compatibility with other software and losslessness
4. I need protection from casual viewing by saving in a file, not the photo library

I can have 2 and 4 by using JPEG.
I can have 1, 3 and 4 with raw data (respectively NSData) made from the camera buffer.
Can I have all 4 of my prerequisites with Xcode and iOS? I am about to give up and looking for your input as a last resort.

While still exploring this, I am also stuck on the other avenue I tried, [libtiff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17169300/how-to-make-libtiff-for-an-xcode-project-and-an-ios-application). I am still trying, though...

Here is the list of great advice I have tried, my own code is just put together from stack overflow sources like these:

- [How to write exif metadata to an image (not the camera roll, just a UIImage or JPEG)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9006759/how-to-write-exif-metadata-to-an-image-not-the-camera-roll-just-a-uiimage-or-j?lq=1) (makes me wish I could use JPEG format, it is so effortless when doing what Apple prefers)
- [Raw image data from camera like “645 PRO”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11612647/raw-image-data-from-camera-like-645-pro) (this would be the point to use e.g. [libtiff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17169300/how-to-make-libtiff-for-an-xcode-project-and-an-ios-application))
- [Saving CGImageRef to a png file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1320988/saving-cgimageref-to-a-png-file) (works with `kUTTypeTIFF`, too, but no metadata)

**Solution**

The complete sequence of actions from `captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection`:

```
[[self myAVCaptureStillImageOutput] captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:videoConnection completionHandler: ^(CMSampleBufferRef imageSampleBuffer, NSError *error)
 {
     //get all the metadata in the image
     CFDictionaryRef metadata = CMCopyDictionaryOfAttachments(kCFAllocatorDefault, imageSampleBuffer, kCMAttachmentMode_ShouldPropagate);
     // get image reference
     CVImageBufferRef imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(imageSampleBuffer);
     // >>>>>>>>>> lock buffer address
     CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(imageBuffer, 0);

     //Get information about the image
     uint8_t *baseAddress = (uint8_t *)CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(imageBuffer);
     size_t bytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(imageBuffer);
     size_t width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(imageBuffer);
     size_t height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(imageBuffer);

     // create suitable color space
     CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

     //Create suitable context (suitable for camera output setting kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA)
     CGContextRef newContext = CGBitmapContextCreate(baseAddress, width, height, 8, bytesPerRow, colorSpace, kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little | kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);

     // <<<<<<<<<< unlock buffer address
     CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(imageBuffer, 0);

     // release color space
     CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

     //Create a CGImageRef from the CVImageBufferRef
     CGImageRef newImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(newContext);

     // release context
     CGContextRelease(newContext);

     // create destination and write image with metadata
     CFURLRef url = (__bridge CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath isDirectory:NO];
     CGImageDestinationRef destination = CGImageDestinationCreateWithURL(url, kUTTypeTIFF, 1, NULL);
     CGImageDestinationAddImage(destination, imageRef, metadata);

     // finalize and release destination
     CGImageDestinationFinalize(destination);
     CFRelease(destination);
 }
```

The still image output related camera settings were:

```
[[self myAVCaptureSession] setSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto];
```

and

```
NSDictionary *outputSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA], (id)kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey, nil];
[myAVCaptureStillImageOutput setOutputSettings:outputSettings];
```

I get a nice nominally uncompressed image in nominal TIFF format with all metadata. (It is mirrored on other systems, but now I can write the EXIF and other metadata, I can also fine-tune that, I am sure).

Thanks again to [Wildaker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1228723/wildaker) for his help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've already cracked 1, 3 and 4, it seems the only hurdle you're missing is saving the data and metadata together. Try this (assuming the unprocessed data is in a `CMSampleBufferRef` called `myImageDataSampleBuffer` and you've done the heavy lifting of putting the graphical data into a `CGImageRef` called `myImage`):

```
CFDictionaryRef metadata = CMCopyDictionaryOfAttachments(kCFAllocatorDefault,
  myImageDataSampleBuffer,
  kCMAttachmentMode_ShouldPropagate);
NSFileManager* fm = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];
NSURL* pathUrl = [fm URLForDirectory:saveDir
  inDomain:NSUserDomainMask
  appropriateForURL:nil
  create:YES
  error:nil];
NSURL* saveUrl = [pathUrl URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"myfilename.tif"];
CGImageDestinationRef destination = CGImageDestinationCreateWithURL((__bridge CFURLRef)saveUrl,
  (CFStringRef)@"public.tiff", 1, NULL);
CGImageDestinationAddImage(destination, myImage, metadata);
CGImageDestinationFinalize(destination);
CFRelease(destination);
```

Comment: I will not forget. I have not yet had the time to try it, because I am fully occupied with another problem in my software at the moment. Promise!

Comment: Please also have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17673587/how-to-load-a-self-made-tiff-image-file-from-nsdocumentsdirectory). How to read those files back in (need to display thumbnail in a `UICollectionView`)?

Answer (score 2):

This thread was very helpful in resolving a very similar problem, so I thought I'd contribute a Swift 2.0 implementation of the solution in case someone comes looking.

```
stillImageOutput?.captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection(videoConnection, completionHandler: { (imageDataSampleBuffer, error) -> Void in


    // get image meta data (EXIF, etc)
    let metaData: CFDictionaryRef? = CMCopyDictionaryOfAttachments( kCFAllocatorDefault, imageDataSampleBuffer, kCMAttachmentMode_ShouldPropagate )


    // get reference to image
    guard let imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer( imageDataSampleBuffer ) else { return }


    // lock the buffer
    CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress( imageBuffer, 0 )


    // read image properties
    let baseAddress = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress( imageBuffer )

    let bytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow( imageBuffer )

    let width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth( imageBuffer )

    let height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight( imageBuffer )


    // color space
    let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()


    // context - camera output settings kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA
    let bitmapInfo = CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: CGImageAlphaInfo.PremultipliedFirst.rawValue).union(.ByteOrder32Little)

    let newContext = CGBitmapContextCreate( baseAddress, width, height, 8, bytesPerRow, colorSpace, bitmapInfo.rawValue )


    //unlock buffer
    CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress( imageBuffer, 0 )

    //Create a CGImageRef from the CVImageBufferRef
    guard let newImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage( newContext ) else {
        return
    }


    // create tmp file and write image with metadata
    let fileName = String(format: "%@_%@", NSProcessInfo.processInfo().globallyUniqueString, "cap.tiff")
    let fileURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory()).URLByAppendingPathComponent(fileName)

    if let destination = CGImageDestinationCreateWithURL( fileURL, kUTTypeTIFF, 1, nil) {

        CGImageDestinationAddImage( destination, newImage, metaData )

        let wrote = CGImageDestinationFinalize( destination )

        if !wrote || NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(fileURL.URLString) {

            return

        }

    }

}
```

p.s. for this to work, you have to configure your image buffer like this:

```
    stillImageOutput = AVCaptureStillImageOutput()

    stillImageOutput?.outputSettings = [ kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey: Int(kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA) ]
```