# How to compose a "right" oriented UIImage with NSData and NSDictionary captured from AVCaptureDevice?

Tags: ios, iphone, uiimageview, uiimage, uiimageorientation

I'm using AVCaptureDevice to capture image from camera. After setting up session, and capturing image, I can get a `NSData *` and a `NSDictionary *` object, however, due to the separation of EXIF meta and data, when I tried to convert the `NSData *` to `UIImage *`, and put it in a `UIImageView *`, the image is misoriented.

I know I can use a lot of *fix* methods to get the image right, and I'm doing it right now, but the thing is, when the image resolution is high (ie, 3000 * 4000), the *fix* method is slow, it takes around 500 milliseconds on my iPhone5. After running time profiler with instruments, the major time is spent on writing data, which is inevitable I guess.

So I'm wondering am I doing the *right* thing? Shouldn't there be a easier yet more efficient way to solve the problem like this? Please help me out of here, big thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible without actually rotating the image bytes by using the ImageIO framework. You want to create an image destination with [CGImageDestinationCreateWithURL](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGImageDestination/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGImageDestinationCreateWithURL), then add your image data along with its EXIF data with [CGImageDestinationAddImage](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGImageDestination/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGImageDestinationAddImage).

There are a couple of examples floating around on SO, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17361100/how-to-save-a-tiff-photo-from-avfoundations-capturestillimageasynchronouslyfromc/17398731#17398731).

If all you want to do is display this image, then you can create a UIImage with a specified rotation from the data using:

```
+ (UIImage *)imageWithCGImage:(CGImageRef)imageRef scale:(CGFloat)scale orientation:(UIImageOrientation)orientation
```

Comment: Thanks Tark, the method you mentioned needs to save the image to a file, right? What if I don't want to save it, I just want to display it within a UIImageView ?

Comment: In that case, all you need to do is to create a UIImage from the data specifying the rotation given in the EXIF metadata. I updated the answer with the method you should be looking at.

Comment: Guess that's what is takes. Thank you for your help!