# Compile libtiff for iOS project to include 64bit architecture

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, xcode

I have an iOS app updated to the latest SDK8.3 and I am using the latest version of Xcode. My app uses libtiff to convert an image (in PNG format) to TIFF format. The problem I have is that I need to submit a new revision to the App Store and needs to incorporate 64 bit architecture. The libtiff library in my project is old and I have to update to the latest version.

I have downloaded libtiff 4.0.3 from the official download site ( ftp.remotesensing.org) but I can't build it for the needed architectures, I get an error. I have read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17169300/how-to-make-libtiff-for-an-xcode-project-and-an-ios-application) but is is a little outdated and I presume Apple changed the toolchain in Xcode 6 compared to Xcode 5 or Xcode 4.

I am not an expert in the gcc / llvm toolchain and I am a bit lost here. I just need the tiff library in my Xcode project and successfully compile it. I've tried to build the library myself but it builds just for OS X and I need iOS.

Documentation about TIFF in iOS is scarce and I would prefer to use PNG, but for business reasons I need to use TIFF. Has anyone successfully compiled libtiff into a fat binary to include the 5 required architectures (i386, x86_64, arm64, armv7, armv7s)?

I only need tiff conversion but without jpg compression, so I am guessing I do not need the jpeg library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had similar problems but fortunately I found this [Github project](https://github.com/ashtons/libtiff-ios). Just follow the instructions and build the libraries. Build libjpg first because is a dependency of liftiff.

Use terminal and go to the folder of the downloaded project, in my case is `liftiff-ios-master`, and run these two scripts, and in this order.

```
./build-jpg.sh
./build-tiff.sh
```

Once finished in the `liftiff-ios-master/dependencies` folder you will find two folders, `include` and `lib` with all the necessary files.

In Xcode just copy the following files to your project (these are just the necessary files for `libtiff`, no need to copy the jpeg library files unless you need jpeg compression support):

[image: libtiff files]

and verify that `liftiff.a` was added to your `Link Binary With Libraries` section of the `Build Phases` tab in your target.

In your .h or .m file just include this:

```
#import <tiffio.h>
```

Compile and run. Make sure the setting `Architectures` of your `Build Settings` is set to `Standard architectures (armv7, arm64)`

To verify that `liftiff.a` has all the desired architectures, within its folder and from the terminal use:

```
$ file libtiff.a
libtiff.a: Mach-O universal binary with 5 architectures
libtiff.a (for architecture armv7):     current ar archive random library
libtiff.a (for architecture armv7s):    current ar archive random library
libtiff.a (for architecture i386):      current ar archive random library
libtiff.a (for architecture x86_64):    current ar archive random library
libtiff.a (for architecture arm64):     current ar archive random library
```